# OpenShift - Sending logs to external TCP server

Tags: node.js, tcp, openshift, syslog, graylog

I'm working on a node.js project inside OpenShift that logs syslog messages to an external TCP Graylog server. 
My code isn't throwing any exception, but I can't see any log on Graylog, how can I test TCP conectivity between OpenShift and Graylog?

For logging, I'm using [winston-syslog](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-syslog) module and I've setted it up like this:

```
let options = {
  protocol: config.getGraylogProtocol(), //tcp4
  host: config.getGraylogHost(), //without "https://", is that ok?
  port: config.getGraylogPort(),
  app_name: config.getAppName()
}
let syslogTransport = new winston.transports.Syslog(options);
```

And then I add this transport to the winston logger.

I've tried (for debuggind purposes) to send plain text to Graylog from a TCP client like this:

```
let net = require("net");
let client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(config.getGraylogPort(), config.getGraylogHost(), () => {
  console.log("CONNECTION WITH GRAYLOG ESTABLISHED"); // this executes!
  client.write("hi graylog"); // but I can't see neither this on graylog
  client.end("bye graylog"); // nor this
});
client.on("data", data => {
  console.log("RECEIVED: " + data); //this doesn't executes
  client.destroy();
});
client.on('error', () => {
  console.log("TCP CONNECTION CLOSED"); //this doesn't executes
})
client.on('close', err => {
  console.log("ERROR ON TCP: " + err); //this doesn't executes
})
```

This block of code is surrounded by a try-catch block but any exception was thrown.

Comment: For pure TCP testing, try `curl`ing the endpoint, or `telnet`.

Comment: @WillGordon ok, I tried curl and I received a time out, now I know that this is a connectivity problem, thanks!